# Need a working Kubectl binary inside an image

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, dockerhub

**My goal is to have a pod with a working Kubectl binary inside.**

Unfortunatly every kubectl image from docker hub I booted using basic yaml resulted in CrashLoopbackOff or else.

Has anyone got some yaml (deployment, pod, etc) that would get me my kubectl ?

---

I tried a bunch of images with this basic yaml there:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kubectl-demo
  labels:
    app: deploy
    role: backend
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: deploy
      role: backend
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: deploy
        role: backend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kubectl-demo
        image: <SOME_IMAGE>
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Thx

Comment: because `kubectl` is not a daemon, so the container dies. Just have a process running inside the container and use kubectl.

Comment: @suren I don't think I can exec inside a crashLoopbackOff pod can I ? How would you propose to run a process inside ?

Comment: I see. Because all images copy from the builder `kubectl` and don't leave shell or bash. Let me craft one that would work.

Comment: Here. Use this image: `viejo/kubelet`. But you can't just run it. Do `kubectl run -it kubectl --image viejo/kubectl sh`. Then exit the container. The container will restart, and will stay running, as it will run `sh` automatically.

Comment: What does the pod actually do?  What would be calling `kubectl` and how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or, you can do this. It works in my context, with kubernetes on VMs, where I know where is `kubeconfig` file. You would need to make the necessary changes, to make it work in your environment.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kubectl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: kubectl
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: kubectl
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: viejo/kubectl
        name: kubelet
        tty: true
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
        - name: kube-config
          mountPath: /root/.kube/
      volumes:
      - name: kube-config
        hostPath:
          path: /home/$USER/.kube/
      affinity:
        nodeAffinity:
          requiredDuringSchedulingIgnoredDuringExecution:
            nodeSelectorTerms:
            - matchExpressions:
              - key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
                operator: Exists
      tolerations:
      - effect: NoSchedule
        key: node-role.kubernetes.io/master
        operator: Exists
```

This is the result:

```
$ kubectl get po
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
kubectl-cb8bfc6dd-nv6ht   1/1     Running   0          70s
$ kubectl exec kubectl-cb8bfc6dd-nv6ht -- kubectl get no
NAME                     STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION
kubernetes-1-17-master   Ready    master   16h   v1.17.3
kubernetes-1-17-worker   Ready    <none>   16h   v1.17.3
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'll need a few days but I'll test that and get back to you. thx

Answer (score 1):

As Suren already explained in the comments that `kubectl` is not a daemon so kubectl will run, exit and cause the container to restart.

There are a couple of workarounds for this. One of these is to use  `sleep` command with `infinity` argument. This would keep the Pod alive, prevent it from restarting and allow you to exec into it.

Here`s an example how to do that:

```
spec:
 containers:
 - image: bitnami/kubectl
   command:
   - sleep 
   - "infinity"
   name: kctl
```

Let me know if this helps.